# Are "feasible generalized least squares" and "iteratively reweighted least squares" the same thing?

Tags: least-squares, terminology

These two techniqies seem closely related:

- [Iteratively reweighted least squares (IRLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares)
- [Feasible generalized least squares (FGLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_generalized_least_squares)

Are the mathematics the same, just different communities (math or stats), like in [Tikhonov regularization or ridge regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)?

Or is there a difference, e.g., that IRLS neglects correlations (after [weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares)) while FGLS does not (after [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, IRLS is a strategy for solving more general *p*-norm minimization problems by means of a sequence of related 2-norm (least squares) problems.

FGLS may be specialized for a diagonal covariance matrix in Feasible Weighted Least Squares (FWLS).